# Class Header , string does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, header

Hi I'm trying to finish my homework. I have a compilation error when I try to separate a class, then call it later. But the whole test function works properly. It has the class within the whole text. Basically when i try to separate the class from the text, I have an error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
 string alpha;
int beta;

public:
Person(string Name, int Age)
{
    alpha = Name;
    beta = Age;
}
string getName()
{
    return alpha;
}
int getAge()
{
    if (beta < 0)
    {   beta = 0;
        cout << "Error. A negative age cannot be entered. " << endl;
        }
    if (beta > 120)
    {
        cout << "Damn you're old. How many heart transplants have you had? You Vampire " << endl;
    }
    return beta;
}
void setName(string alpha)
{

}
void setAge(int beta);
void display();

};

int main()
{


Person Lu("Jess ", 22);
Person Rose("Gary ", 49);
cout << Lu.getAge() << "   " << Lu.getName() <<endl;
cout << Rose.getAge() << "   " << Rose.getName() << endl;
return 0;
}`
```

But when i separate the class,:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
private:
   string alpha;
  int beta;

public:
    Person(string Name, int Age)
{
    alpha = Name;
    beta = Age;
}
string getName()
{
    return alpha;
}
int getAge()
{
    if (beta < 0)
    {   beta = 0;
        cout << "Error. A negative age cannot be entered. " << endl;
        }
    if (beta > 120)
    {
        cout << "Damn you're old. How many heart transplants have you had? You Vampire " << endl;
    }
    return beta;
}
void setName(string alpha)
{

}
void setAge(int beta);
void display();

};
```

Main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

Person Lu("Jess ", 22);
cout << Lu.getAge() << "   " << Lu.getName() <<endl;

    return 0;
}`
```

But when I separate the class i get an error in codeblocks. Please help.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: line 7 error: 'string' does not name a type

Comment: You should edit that into your question.

Comment: I don't think that's the actual error, because it compiled when the 2 files were together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put `using namespace std;` in Person.h.

Also, you don't have any header guards on Person.h, which won't cause a problem in such a simple program, but will as soon as multiple files include Person.h.

Comment: @MichaelLa I should mention that having `using namespace std;` in a header is very dangerous. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice